# Run validation for one field in Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I need to run validators for some particular field without affecting model validation state. How can this be done?

The context for this is that there is validation hook that is intended for validating one field (`foo`) but it requires to be sure that (`bar`) is ok first.

```
...
bar: {
  required: true,
  type: Number,
  min: 2,
  max: 10,
  validator: isInteger
}
...

function validateFoo(foo, bar) {
  // the code below will throw if bar is not an integer between 2 and 10
  ...
}

schema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  if (/* check if model.bar is valid */) {
    if (!validateFoo(model.foo, model.bar)) {
      model.invalidate('foo', 'foo is invalid');
    }
  } else {
    model.invalidate('foo', 'foo is invalid because of bar');
  }

  next();
});
```

Doing this by not using existing `bar` schema validators will result in WET code:

```
schema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  // WET!
  if (model.bar >= 2 && model.bar <= 10 && isInteger(model.bar))
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, Please have you gotten a solution to this?

Comment: @olawalejuwonm IIRC, no. Likely custom validators is the way, like suggested below. Consider posting if you'll come up with something

Comment: I haven't find an answer yet @Esus Flask

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Custom Validators section here :
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

This way, the **bar** validator will run before your pre-validate hook.

Also, I don't see why the validation of one field would rely on another. Perhaps, you should be a bit more explicit about what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the documentation. It doesn't answer the question. I'm aware that pre hook runs before validators.I need to run validators for bar *manually*. Because validateFoo expects that bar is already a valid value (number, higher than 2, etc). Otherwise I have to check this additionally in validateFoo, and this looks WET - these rules were already defined in schema for bar. I hoped that the question is specific enough on that.

Comment: IMO, you won't be able to have DRY code in your case (at least with mongoose). You can force validation on a document but you can't force validation on a specific attribute.

Then, you have 2 options : 
1) Use custom validators for both
2) Check both value in pre hook